# why html doctype dtd make css style.top not working in firefox 8.0.1

Tags: html, css

I'm learning dhtml using google's sample 
http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/samples/dhtmltest.html

however, when i add below doctype dtd into the source code, the moveup/down will not work any more in firefox 8.0.1

mostly, i think below statement is not working anymore

```
myObj.style.top = texttop;
```

could anyone advise? thx.

below is the source code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<html lang="en">
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Example</TITLE>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
body {font: 14px arial;
color: #000066;
}
#myText {position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 400px;
font: 24px arial;
font-weight: 900;
}
</STYLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">


var texttop = 100;
var textleft = 400;
function vanish(flag) {
var myObj = new getObj('myText');
myObj.style.visibility = (flag) ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
}
function moveUpDown(amount) {
var myObj = new getObj('myText');

texttop += amount;
myObj.style.top = texttop;
}
function moveLR(amount) {
var myObj = new getObj('myText');
textleft += amount;
myObj.style.left = textleft;
}
function changeColor(color) {
var myObj = new getObj('myText');
myObj.style.color = color;
}
function changeStyle(style) {
var myObj = new getObj('myText');
myObj.style.fontStyle = style;
}
function getObj(name) {
if (document.getElementById) {
this.obj = document.getElementById(name);
this.style = document.getElementById(name).style;
}
else
return;
}
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV ID="myText">Change Me!</DIV>
<p>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:moveUpDown(40);">Down</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:moveUpDown(-40);">Up</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:moveLR(-40);">Left</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:moveLR(+40);">Right</A><BR>
<p>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:changeColor('orange')">Orange</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:changeColor('green')">Green</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:changeColor('purple')">Purple</A><BR>
<P>
<a CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:changeStyle('italic')" class="nohover">Italic</a><br>
<a CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:changeStyle('normal')" class="nohover">Normal</a><br>
<p>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:vanish(1)">Vanish!</A><BR>
<A CLASS="page" HREF="javascript:vanish(0)">Re-appear</A><BR>
<p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: By the way, `using href="javascript: ..."` is not a good idea. In most cases, you can put the javascript handler in the `onclick` attribute and leave the `href` for actual jumps to other locations.

Comment: thx. could you talk a bit more about the differences? why we should not do that?

Comment: That's just what they are meant for. Using `href` for a javascript handler instead of jumping to another page basically means you're abusing it. But if you use them the way they're designed, you can differentiate between situation where the user has Javascript enabled or not. E.G. use the `onclick` for an AJAX call, and the `href` for a reload of the page (enabling you to do the handling server-side, if it can't be done client-side).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In quirks mode (without a DOCTYPE declaration), you can get away with giving something a value of, say, "40", and the browser will assume pixels.

However, in strict mode (when using a good DOCTYPE declaration), you will need to be explicit and say "40px" for 40 pixels.
So all you need to do is write

```
myObj.style.top = texttop+'px';
```

to be compatible with the standard, and it will work both with and without a DOCTYPE declaration.

Comment: thx! this works now! when searching differences between quirks mode vs standard mode, I did not get a good reference helping me find this out. could you give some good links/advices? thx

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_Quirks_Mode_Behavior) is a list of quirks in Firefox. Other browsers have mostly the same quirks (since they all try to emulate Netscape 4), but there are differences. So using strict mode in your HTML files is better if you want your webpages to look the same in different browsers.